# malloc call changing subroutine parameter struct's fields

Tags: c, struct

I am implementing a linked list of structs, but I am getting a very odd error in a subroutine call. I have two structs, a student and a request as follows:

```
  9 struct request{
 10         char class_name[24];
 11         struct request * next_request;
 12 };
 13 
 14 struct student{
 15         struct request * request_list;
 16         int request_total;
 17         struct student * next_student;
 18         char name[24];
 19         };
```

and I am using a subroutine call to add to a students request_list

```
104 void add_request(struct student * student, char* class_name){
105         student->request_total = student->request_total+1;
106         printf("%s before\n", student->name);
107         fflush(stdout);
108         
109         struct request * new_req = malloc(sizeof(struct request));
110         
110         printf("%s after\n", student->name);
110         fflush(stdout);
111         // other stuff ...
```

but the malloc call is changing the student structs name fields as I get the following as output:

```
Bob  before
1 after
```

does anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT:
It was a very stupid error on my part, I found it.
For a new student, under a specific condition, I was malloc()ing the size of a student pointer before the subroutine call, rather than for a student. I still don't know why the error was only occurring after that line though, that is what threw me off.
Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I changed it, but nothing, thanks though

Comment: I'm guessing you have a use-after-free or similar bug somewhere in your code. I would look into valgrind.

Comment: Your `student->name` pointer is probably pointing to freed memory. That kind of works until that memory is reused, which happens in that `malloc()` call. If that's the case the actual error lies elsewhere.

Comment: pointer `student` is pointing to an invalid memory area.

Comment: The code, as presented in your question, should not exhibit the behavior you describe. Is that actual code, with nothing except the allocation happening between the two printouts?

Comment: First, check the place you declare each `student` struct. Second, check the place you assign `student->name`. If you use `free`, it should be checked too.

Comment: The problem is in the code that you did not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at where you are calling add_request() and the student pointer passed to it.  Most likely, the memory that student is pointing to is not allocated properly or it was inadvertently freed before the call to add_request.  Are you certain you are passing a pointer to the correct element in the linked list and not accidently passing a pointer to one that was discarded earlier?

While it is probably not causing this issue, since you are declaring class name and student name as arrays, you may also need to consider that you may have a student name or request name that is too long for the array somewhere.